# Sharing the same component in ReactJS routes with different url parameters not updating content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm new to ReactJS and I'm unsure if I'm simply doing this wrong (I'm sure I am to a certain extent!) or I just need to change something.

So Basically I'm pulling in some JSON from a Drupal web service. My content pages are basically just the same page, a header and some paragraph text. So I thought the best way to deal with this was to have one component that fetched and displayed the page which changes by the ID fed into the url.

I'm using React Router Dom (v4), when I reload the page it gets the correct page with the correct ID but if I click on the navigation menu it will only ever show the first page you clicked on, but does update the route in the address bar.

I am using Fetch API and the call is made in componentDidMount, I've googled it a lot and it seemed I need to do something with componentWillReceiveProps as componentDidMount is doing what it's supposed to do and only update when the component is first mounted on the page. But I can't figure out how to use componentWillReceiveProps correctly. I kind of have it working (but not really) if I literally put the same function in both componentWillReceiveProps and componentDidMount but that seems wrong to me... This is my component:

```
import React from 'react';

var urlForSimplePage = id =>
`page-url/${id}`

class SimplePage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            requestFailed: false,
            open: true,
        }
    }
    fetchSimplePage() {
         fetch(urlForSimplePage(this.props.match.params.id))
          .then(response => {
           if (!response.ok) {
             throw Error("Network request failed")
          }

          return response
         })
        .then(d => d.json())
        .then(d => {
           this.setState({
             SimplePageData: d
           })
        }, () => {
          this.setState({
             requestFailed: true
          })
      })
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      this.fetchSimplePage();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      this.fetchSimplePage();
  }

  render() {


  if (this.state.requestFailed) return <p>Failed!</p>
    if (!this.state.SimplePageData) return <p>Loading...</p>
   return (

<div>
    <h1>
      {this.state.SimplePageData[0].title[0].value}
    </h1>
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: this.state.SimplePageData[0].body[0].value} } />
</div>
)
  }
}

export default SimplePage;
```

Comment: where is your `<Route>` ?

Comment: in it's own component, I import all the components the route uses into that i.e. this page is imported onto the page with the router

Comment: Can you try using componentDidUpdate lifecycle, check if the previous id is not equal to the current id and if not, invoke fetchSimplePage method.